# Submitting a form to php without it redirecting to a new page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have the following form (bootstrap used and is required) to send data to my "main.php" file, and it returns a JSON encoded array.

```
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="get" action="main.php">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="question" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Question:</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="question" name="question" placeholder="Please ask me a question" value="">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-2">
            <input id="submit" name="submit" type="submit" value="Send" class="btn btn-secondary">
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

The array is stored and 'echoed' in this way:

```
<?php
$responsesArray = array(
            array(
                'template' => $template,
                'twitter' => $twitterOutput
                )
            );

        echo json_encode($responsesArray);
?>
```

I would like this to not redirect me to "main.php", but to give the result to a JQuery function and be displayed on my original page.

Here is the script I have so far, but it doesn't work, can someone explain why?

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
$("submit").submit(function(event)
{
    event.preventDefault();
    /* call the php that has the php array which is json_encoded */
    $.getJSON('main.php', function(data) 
    {
        /* data will hold the php array as a javascript object */ 
        $.each(data, function(index, value) 
        {
            $('ul').append('<li id="' + index + '">' + value.template + '\n' + value.twitter + ' ' + '</li>'); 
        });
    });
});

</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

You should bind the event listener to the form, not to the submit button

```
$("form").submit(function(event){/* ... */});
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `submit()`, use `click()` function. Your jQuery should be like this:

```
$("#submit").click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    /* call the php that has the php array which is json_encoded */
    $.getJSON('main.php', function(data) 
    {
        /* data will hold the php array as a javascript object */ 
        $.each(data, function(index, value) 
        {
            $('ul').append('<li id="' + index + '">' + value.template + '\n' + value.twitter + ' ' + '</li>'); 
        });
    });
});
```

**Better Solution:**

If you want *dynamic* behavior, then use `on()` instead of `click()`. The `click()` binding is called a "direct" binding which will only attach the handler to elements that already exist. It won't get bound to elements created in the future. To do that, you'll have to create a "delegated" binding by using `on()`.

So your jQuery should be like this:

```
$(document).on('click','#submit',function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    /* call the php that has the php array which is json_encoded */
    $.getJSON('main.php', function(data) 
    {
        /* data will hold the php array as a javascript object */ 
        $.each(data, function(index, value) 
        {
            $('ul').append('<li id="' + index + '">' + value.template + '\n' + value.twitter + ' ' + '</li>'); 
        });
    });
});
```

From the [documentation of .on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/):

> Delegated events have the advantage that they can process events from descendant elements that are added to the document at a later time.

Comment: Only problem with this is that the form can be submitted without clicking on the submit button, for example by pressing enter while having focus on the text input

Comment: @balping *By pressing enter while having focus on the text input* you're actually submitting the form.

Comment: Yeah. Because of this, your solution is not enough, your code only listens on button clicks

Comment: Thanks, this now works, but the correct things are not being appended, what is wrong with the .append line?

Comment: @TomRobson What's your expected output?

Comment: My php takes a template with a # placeholder and replaces it with a keyword, but it is returning the template without either the # or the keyword. It is also not returning the twitterString (from twitter api) at all. Both of these worked with the normal form submission method of loading a new page for main.php

Answer (score 0):

Return false at the end of either the form submit event or the submit button's click event.

This is a simple example:

```
<form id='form' action='main.php'>
<input id='submit' type='submit' value='Submit'>
</form>

<script>
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
    // Disable using form submission event
    document.getElementById('form').onsubmit = function() {
        alert('Still here: submit');
        return false;
    };

    // Disable using submit button click event
    document.getElementById('submit').onclick = function() {
        alert('Still here: click');
        return false;
    };
});
</script>
```